# Ping a website with output to Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, ping

I try to ping a website and display the output in real-time to a Label. Problem : the command makes an infinite loop (nom_mp4 = tk.Label(root, text=line) and the code stop before nom_mp4.pack(). 
Someone has an idea to make it work?
This is my code :

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
import Tkinter as tk 
from Tkinter import *

def commande():
    cmd = 'ping www.wikipedia.com'
    p = Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
    for line in iter(p.stdout.readline,''):
        nom_mp4 = tk.Label(root, text=line)
        nom_mp4.pack()

root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x190+400+400')

browsebutton2 = tk.Button(root,text='Ping',command=commande) #le bouton browse
browsebutton2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why are you calling ping? Do you care about the response times, or do you just care that you can connect to the website? What actual information do you need to display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use threading.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import Tk
from threading import Thread


def create_worker(target):
    return Thread(target=target)


def start_worker(worker):
    worker.start()


def commande():
    cmd = 'ping www.wikipedia.com'
    p = Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
    for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, ''):
        nom_mp4 = tk.Label(root, text=line)
        nom_mp4.pack()

root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x190+400+400')

worker = create_worker(commande)
tk.Button(root, text='Ping', command=lambda: start_worker(worker)).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: tkinter isn't thread safe. This code might work, it might not.

Comment: I have a similar app but want to ping mullite servers  to different outputs (1 line) with in the same root window.

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd = 'ping www.wikipedia.com'
```

This will run infinite. You need to define how many times you want it to run. And maybe not ping a website when you are testing. For example:

```
cmd = 'ping -c 10 localhost'
```

`-c 10` tells ping to run 10 times. `localhost` is just pinging your own machine, replace with URL when you have it working as intended.

You should also move the creation of the `tk.Label` outside of the `for-loop`. You don't need to create a new label each time, you just need to change the `text` value of the label. If you create and pack it after the `tk.Button`, it will appear below the button in the window.

To update the `text` of a `tk.Label`, you can do something like:

```
nom_mp4.configure(text=new_value_here)
```

The window will not be updated while the `for-loop` runs, and it will be "locked" until the loop has finished. To have it update you can put this at the end of the `for-loop`:

```
root.update_idletasks()
```

The window will still be locked though. To fix this I belive you will have to look into `threading` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

It works ! I have changed the code with your suggestions. I didn't put the -c option on the ping command because I wanted ping to work on its own without blocking the program. I changed the position of the pack outside of the loop as suggested by Oystein-hr and update the text with a configure. I also insert a threading with the example of Josh Leeb-du Toit.
Thanks guys.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import Tk
from threading import Thread


def create_worker(target):
    return Thread(target=target)


def start_worker(worker):
    worker.start()


def commande():
    cmd = 'ping localhost'
    p = Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
    for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, ''):
        result.configure(text=line)

root = Tk()
root.geometry('600x80+400+400')

worker = create_worker(commande)
tk.Button(root, text='Ping', command=lambda: start_worker(worker)).pack()

result = tk.Label(root)
result.pack()

root.mainloop()
```